# Postgresql 9.4 - pg_largeobject size does't correspond with the size of stored objects?

Tags: database, postgresql, size, vacuum

I've got a database which has approximately 43GB. When I count the **size of pg_largeobject table** it gives me **43GB** too:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('pg_largeobject'));
```

When I sum **the sizes of all large objects** by the following command:

```
SELECT sum(length(pg.data)) FROM pg_largeobject pg;
```

it gives me **32.5GB**. I've tried to unlink all objects apart from the desirable ones by:

```
SELECT lo_unlink(l.loid)
FROM   pg_largeobject l
GROUP  BY loid
HAVING (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_file t WHERE t.file_content = l.loid))
AND    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM license t WHERE t.attachment_content = l.loid))
AND    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM personal_license t WHERE t.attachment_content = l.loid))
AND    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM scenario t WHERE t.scenario_file = l.loid))
AND    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM service_result t WHERE t.content = l.loid));
```

and run VACUUM:

`VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject;`

When I tried it once, it reduced the size from 47GB to 43 but **I cannot find the missing 10.5 GB** Do you know what can be stored there or what should I do?